# How can i check if there's nothing type on the search bar and if it a number return nothing?

Tags: javascript

How can I check if the user types nothing in the search bar and if its a number return nothing. And also, how do I clear the user recent value? I've manage to clear the value, but after the conditional statement using the same input.value = '', i receive an error.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
 e.preventDefault();
 input.value = ''; // I'm assuming this get overwritten;

 if(input.value === '') {
  console.error('Please type anything in the search bar');
 } else {
  return recipes();
 }
});
```

So from the code above, when the user types in nothing it will spit our error in the console, and if users were to type in both A-Z and 0-9 the recipes will still load.

I've left with when users type in numbers it will spit out error in console and lastly, to clear user input value after typing.

This is a practice for my beginner portfolio.

Comment: Why are you clearing the input before the `if` condition? (Assuming  you have written`input = document.getElementById(<your id>)` somewhere)

Comment: use `e.target.value` instead of `input.value`

Comment: @adiga Because i just need the conditional statement right. Thanks for reaching out to me :D

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to set input.value to null, it'll be setup to the default value into the HTML tag.

Also, this depend on how you define your `input` variable, if it's common like the following example, it's will work fine with `input.value`

```js
let form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]
let input = document.querySelector('[type=text]')

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
 e.preventDefault();

 if(input.value === '') {
  console.error('Please type anything in the search bar');
 } else {
  console.log(`Submitted value: ${input.value}`) // Get directly from the input
 }
});

// Another example:
input.addEventListener('input', e => {

 // Easy way to get the value of the element who trigger the current `e` event
 console.log(`Input updated: ${e.currentTarget.value}`)
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: I assume that you did not get my question. Question 1, How to clear users value after they type? Question 2, if users were to type in numbers, i don't want any recipes to pop out. I'm making a recipes ideas.

Comment: I'll not do your job :) Just try to explain what you didn't understand